# Using dynamic markers in a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, mapping

I'm working on a dynamic mapping application that receives a series of data as JSON and then converts the data to a map point with a pop up in Leaflet.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
"unit":"90",
"latitude":36.120915,
"longitude":-97.0633733,
"velocity":0.022,
"heading":102.9,
"timestamp":"Wed, 23 Nov 2011 20:00:28 GMT"
}
```

I have a listener setup to receive this data from a push server which calls the below function to draw the unit's location on the map.

```
function drawUnit(unit)
{
    //removeUnitMarkers();

    var popupContent = "<h3>" + unit.number + "</h3>";
    popupContent = popupContent + "<p><strong>Direction: </strong>" + unit.heading + "<br />";
    popupContent = popupContent + "<strong>Speed: </strong>" + unit.velocity + "<br />";
    popupContent = popupContent + "<strong>Last Update:</strong> " + unit.timestamp + "<br /></p>";
    var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(unit.latitude,unit.longitude);
    var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
    var unitNumber = unit.number;
    var unitTest = 'test';

    console.log(unitData);
    unitLayerGroup.addLayer(marker);
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
    //unitMarkerCache.push(marker);
    //map.panTo(markerLocation);
}
```

This works for a single unit but I need it to work for 2 or more units.

I'm struggling to think about what to do to draw the units on the map and be able to call a unique marker to destroy it and then redraw it. I've thought about defining an array or object to hold the data but I can't get it to work with a unit's number as part of the variable name.

```
var marker[unit.number] = {"unit":unit.number, "latitude":unit.latitude};
```

Doing something like the above `var marker[unit.number]` doesn't work; Firebug always throws an error:

```
missing ; before statement
```

http://10.10.1.10:86/map2.php
Line 161

This is line 161: `var marker[unit.number] = new L.Marker(markerLocation);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your eventlistener is setup, and how many unique units you have. but If you only have one unit = "90" and want to plot its location by listening to data sent from that unit, this code will work.

```
pointMarkers = [];
var listener = new EventSource("your event source");
listener.addEventListener('your call', function(e){

  points = JSON.parse(e.data);

  if(points.unit = '90') {
    for (var i =0; i < pointMarkers.length; i++) {
      mymap.removeLayer(pointMarkers[i]);

    }
    marker = L.marker([points.latitude, points.longitude]).addTo(mymap);
    pointMarkers.push(marker);
  }   
}, false);
```